# PHP Cookies issues

Tags: php, cookies

Hi :) This is very strange -- I am making the call:

```
setcookie("ApplicationUserRank", "test", mktime (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, time()+60*60*24*30));
```

And then, in another file, calling:

```
echo $_COOKIE["ApplicationUserRank"];
```

However, the echo is blank! I am not really sure what I am doing wrong here, anyone care to explain? :)

EDIT:
Following Richard's suggestion, I ran the following code:

```
echo "COOKIE: " . $_COOKIE["ApplicationUserRank"];
```

Directly after setting the cookie. Still blank! Something seriously strange is happening.

EDIT to my EDIT:

Turns out, that re-runnign the code DOES display the cookie! I guess $_COOKIE does not load from setcookie commands. In fact now that I think about it, I read about that somewhere... Anyways, it would seem that the SAME web file is capable of reading these cookies... Just not any other cookies. (This all is of course after applying many fixes suggested below)

Comment: where is the setcookie() call being done?

Comment: Try to debug with: `$_COOKIE`. There really isn't anything regarding "ApplicationUserRank" ?

Comment: I'm just speculating, but it seems that you're storing important user data within the cookie, I would suggest taking a look at SESSIONS, more information here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php .

Comment: Year 9001 is an invalid Unix timestamp date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trusting Tarek's answer, and taking into consideration what rlemon says, it might prove useful to try the functions `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()`. They are output buffer controlling functions.

As an example:

```
<?php
// php starts collecting the buffer rather than just sending it all out.
ob_start();

if(!isset($_COOKIE["ApplicationUserRank"])) {
    // This should throw an error about headers already being sent or the cookie wouldn't be set, yet under these circumstances, this will work perfectly.
    echo "Cookie has been set.";
    setcookie("ApplicationUserRank", "new test", mktime (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 9001));
}
else {
    echo "Cookie is set.";
}

// now it sends the buffer all at once.
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

`ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` are also necessary for implementing today's fashions (like encryption) if you have no server-side support for it. Click [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) for further reading material.

EDIT:

After reading Gumbo's comment and checking [PHP mktime's page](http://php.net/mktime). [Considering 9001 is an invalid year for UNIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), `mktime()` would always return -1, thus [deleting the cookie](http://php.net/setcookie).
A solution would be as follows:

```
setcookie("ApplicationUserRank", "new test", time()+60*60*24*30); // This should set the expiration date within 30 days from current time.
```

Comment: If PHP creates output before the ob_start() function is called, a call to setcookie() will still throw a "headers already sent" error.

Comment: This looks VERY useful, and I will indeed be using it from now on! However, sadly, it did not resolve the issue :(

Comment: Ahh, thank you :) Unfortunately that did not work either .I did try it in combination with ob_start and ob_end_flush as well. Something seriously seems to be going a wry here... I know it can't be the server config, I have wordpress running and it is storing cookies just fine.

Comment: Ok, lets see. First, I'd like to assume you set your cookies before you send any output (according to PHP's setcookie's page, this is necessary). Second, your cookie doesn't rely on mktime any more. Next thing I can think of is the path and domain variables, try setting them accordingly, check http://php.net/setcookie . Also, check your server configuration. I sense something weird lol

Comment: Hi :) Thanks for staying with me through all of this. I think you are right! There is probably something messed up with my configuration. I have done more testing: I turns out, that the process of submitting a form seems to be removing the cookie that I set! If I manually navigate to the page reading the cookie, WITHOUT going through my form process, that webpage can finally reach the cookie! I am confused as to why this is -- It does not happen with the WordPress cookies....

Comment: Hmm! I looked in the source code of Wordpress, and it looks like they are setting cookies like so: setcookie( 'name', value, expire, '/'); $_COOKIE['name'] = value; I am going to try this myself and see if it somehow works.

Comment: No, it doesn't sadly :( THough I did notice something else: The original cookie that I was playing with somehow managed to keep itself alive. I think navigating away from the page that had the form somehow managed to permanently save the cookie. I dunno

Comment: Well, my shot is, then, definitely for configuration problem. I mean, there is something really weird in there (the thing is its either your browser or your server, have you tried any other browsers?).

Answer (score 2):

> setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the
>   HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any
>   output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This
>   requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output,
>   including  and  tags as well as any whitespace.
>
> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page
>   load with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays. Note, superglobals
>   such as $_COOKIE became available in PHP 4.1.0. Cookie values also
>   exist in $_REQUEST.

it is likely that you have something being output to the browser before you set the cookie.
This is the only thing I can think of.

See Examples:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE["ApplicationUserRank"]))
{
    setcookie("ApplicationUserRank", "new test", mktime (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 9001));
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE["ApplicationUserRank"]))
{
echo    $_COOKIE["ApplicationUserRank"];
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

will pass, however

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE["ApplicationUserRank"]))
{
    setcookie("ApplicationUserRank", "new test", mktime (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 9001));
}

if(isset($_COOKIE["ApplicationUserRank"]))
{
echo    $_COOKIE["ApplicationUserRank"];
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

will fail

Comment: Hello :) Thank you very much for the reply. I am absolutely positive that nothing is being outputted before the cookie sets though :(

Comment: can you please provide more insight to the code you are using then. As my example executes as expected. I cannot help if the vital information is not provided.

Comment: also, whitespace will be considered 'output' as well. keep that in mind.

Comment: I have my code set up as follows: A PHP space at the top where cookies are set. (Before this, an includes file is loaded. Nothing in the includes will post any content) After this block, HTML is placed, and there is also some intermitted PHP inside that HTML. Nothing complex or fancy, really.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome or Safari there is a resources tab on the web inspector that'll allow you too see the cookies set. Check that to see if the cookie in fact exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine , i tested it and the cookie is being set .

Check to see if you don't change the value of that cookie in another file .

Comment: Cookie value is only being set within that file